# What's wrong with my query debscribed below?

Tags: mysql, sql

It wont return anything .. I get an error below

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects 
WHERE 1 
AND category_id =10 
AND position ASC ORDER BY limit 0,16
```

.. the error says

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ASC ORDER BY limit 0,16' at line 1`

Comment: whats your requirement exactly?

Comment: `Where 1` is meaningless in SQL, as is `AND position ASC ORDER BY limit 0,16`. Have you cut and pasted this from somewhere incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword `asc` is used only *in* the `order by` clause.  Not before it.  Also, `order by` requires one or more column or expressions.  Perhaps you mean:

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects 
WHERE 1 
AND category_id =10 
ORDER BY position asc
limit 0,16
```

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your query, I think you are trying to get "everything" on table "projects", with "category 10", ordered by "position", and limit the results to the first 16 rows.

If that guess is correct, maybe you meant this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects 
WHERE category_id = 10 
ORDER BY position ASC 
LIMIT 16
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well. Not sure where the `...where 1 and ...` come into play, but everything you put here seems like what they are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's wrong with your query:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE 1 AND category_id =10 AND position
```

`WHERE 1` and `AND position` make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: And what did you figure out?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the Where Clause

SELECT * 
FROM projects 
WHERE 1  -> here you should be comparing column to á value
AND category_id =10 
AND position ASC ORDER BY limit 0,16 //position value is missing

it should be some thing like

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects 
WHERE  place = 'London' //place is column name
AND category_id =10 
AND position = 1 ASC ORDER BY limit 0,16  //position value is 1
```